# Почему cURL ничего не возвращает?

Tags: php, парсер, curl

Здравствуйте, не могу понять, почему запрос cURL ничего не возвращает, даже проверил на ошибку curl_error тоже ничего не выводит. Что здесь не так? Прошу помочь кто в теме разобраться. Кстати, пользовался программой Burp Suite для отслеживания заголовков, почему-то в статусе запроса там нет 200, не знаю, имеет ли это значение. Вот мой код, пароль и логин я не пишу:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
function request( $url, $post = null, $cookiefile = 'tmp/cookie.txt' ){
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64)    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
                    'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8', 
                    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
                    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
                    'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
                    'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
                    'Connection:keep-alive',
                    'Content-Length:122',
                    'Origin: http://www.3dcontentcentral.com',
                    ]);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.3dcontentcentral.com/default.aspx');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8080');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);

if( $post ){
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post );
}


if(curl_exec($ch) === false){
  echo 'Ошибка curl: ' . curl_error($ch);
}else{
  echo 'Операция завершена без каких-либо ошибок';
}

$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close( $ch );
return $html;
}


file_put_contents('tmp/cookie.txt','');

$post = '{'.'"loginData":'.json_encode([
'Login' => 'mylogin',
'Password' => "mypass", 
'RememberMe' => false, 
'LoginAsSupplier'=> false, 
'CatalogId' => ""
]).'}';

$html = request('http://www.3dcontentcentral.com/default.aspx/Login', $post);
echo $html;
```

Comment: зачем два раза выполнять курл? попробуйте конструкцию `if (($html = curl_exec($curl)) !== false && $html !== '') {}` Что вообще ни один echo  не выводится?

Comment: Да, страница пустая и не выводится ничего.

Comment: Спасибо, код исправил, но поведение такое же - все страница все время грузится и не выводит ничего.

Comment: Убрал в коде строчки curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8080');  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP); Теперь выводит Операция завершена без каких-либо ошибок{"d":""}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно хардкодить Content-Length, уберите этот заголовок. И еще вам правильно сделали замечание по поводу двойного вызова curl_exec. Проверял через fiddler, все отправляется и принимается - код работает.

Comment: Спасибо, что проверили код, знать что работает - уже хорошо. Теперь бы получить на экран результат. Если я правильно понимаю, то должна страница вывестись с авторизованным пользователем.

Comment: После авторизации возможно будет пустая страница с редиректом, все зависит от сайта. Может вам куки выдались после авторизации, эти куки можно использовать для последующей навигации по сайту.

Comment: Когда авторизуюсь в браузере, то редиректа не наблюдаю, можно на любой странице авторизоваться - страница та же остается, авторизация на ajax, куки ставятся.

Comment: вот с этими куками и зайдите на нужную страницу

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Вот эта строчка curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile); не подразумевает, что кукисы вытаскиваются  и под ними работает скрипт? В том же файле я с помощью file_get_contents подтянул новую страницу и вывел, но все равно вижу форму авторизации

Comment: @ZaurK, подразумевает. То есть вы после первого request сделали второй, к другой странице например, но уже как авторизированный пользователь, потому что у вас куки эти есть. А что вы собственно хотите получить?

Comment: Хочу авторизоваться на сайте. Что-то начало проясняться, то есть я должен второй request отправить, заново инициировав curl_init и куки поставить?

Comment: После авторизации сделайте $html = request('нужная страница', null);
echo $html; и посмотрите, выдалась ли она вам как авторизированному пользователю.

Comment: Она так же выдается с формой авторизации...

Comment: Вроде зашел, спасибо!